# c++ program successfully build, No output, only show stack trace

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, iostream

Successfully Build, but Netbeans Run outputs stack trace

Stack trace:

```
Frame     Function  Args
0022C694  7570EFA3  (00000108, 0000EA60, 00000000, 0022C7B8)
..............
End of stack trace
```

I am reading a file line-by-line and check if they have vowel using C++ class concept.

I have tested read a file line-by-line and out to write a file line-by-line successfully without using C++ class.

Please help to point out where i should change my code. I guess there is memory management problems.

Thank you very much!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Password{
    private:
         char *pwd;
    public:
        Password(const char*pwd){
            setPassword(pwd);
        }
        ~Password(){
            delete []pwd;
        }
        void setPassword(const char *pwd){
            delete []this->pwd;
            if(pwd!=NULL){
                this->pwd=new char[strlen(pwd)+1];
                strcpy(this->pwd,pwd);
            }else{
                 this->pwd=NULL;
                }
        }
        char *getPassword(){
            return this->pwd;
        }
        bool containsVowel(){
            int i,counter=0;
            for(i=0;i<strlen(this->pwd);i++){
            if(this->pwd[i]== 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' )
                counter++;
             }
            if (counter>0)
                return true;
            return false;
      }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ifstream infile("C:/Users/user/Desktop/say.in"); 
    ofstream outfile("C:/Users/user/Desktop/say.out");
    string str; 
    while (getline(infile,str)){
       const char *pwd=str.c_str();
       Password pwdObj(pwd);
       if (pwdObj.containsVowel()==true){
    outfile<<"<"<<str<<"> is accpetable\r\n";
    }

    }
    infile.close();
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You almost certainly have memory management issues here. You `delete` on destruction, but do not `new` (or even init your pointer to `NULL`!) on construction, and have no copy constructor/`op=`. Read up about RAII and the Rule Of Three. And is there something wrong with `std::string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things.  First one is that the `pwd` member of `Password` is not initialized, which will probably cause `setPassword(...)` to fail on the first call.  You could initialize in your constructor like so (argument renamed to avoid confusion):

```
    Password(const char *apwd) : pwd(0) {
        setPassword(apwd);
    }
```

The second problem is that `containsVowel` is quite broken as you've posted it. The variable `i` is also not initialized and I'm guessing there should be a loop --- looks like it's been omitted.  Also there is a problem with the comparison that Delan has noted in his reply.

You could also consider making the `pwd` member a [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).  It would make your life somewhat easier, both in terms of memory management, and finding vowels --- I'm thinking you could use [`str.find_first_of(...)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/) to find the vowels without iterating through all the characters yourself.

Comment: Password(const char *pwd){
            this->pwd=NULL;
            setPassword(pwd);
        }      problem solved, thanks a lot!

Comment: You can probably spare yourself a lot of visual clutter by removing `this->` everywhere... and do initialize `pwd` to zero!

Answer (score 1):

```
if(this->pwd[i]== 'a' || 'e' || 'i' || 'o' || 'u' )
```

should be

```
if(this->pwd[i]== 'a' || this->pwd[i]== 'e' || this->pwd[i]== 'i' || this->pwd[i]== 'o' || this->pwd[i]== 'u' )
```

Comment: not really, after trying your suggesstion, smae problem still persists

Comment: That is merely one issue with your code. There are probably others.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question, but it's certainly a valid observation and something that _must_ be fixed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
        delete []this->pwd;
        if(pwd!=NULL){
            this->pwd=new char[strlen(pwd)+1];
```

what happens if this->pwd is NULL?